# bootrun is failing after migrating to spring boot 3.2.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle, build.gradle

after migrating from spring boot : 3.1.5 to 3.2.3 getting error: require single bean by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration` but found 7 and Action was given `Ensure that your compiler is configured to use the '-parameters' flag`.

gradle is already running with `-parameters` flag but still bootrun is failing. what can be done to avoid this.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '4.3.1.3277'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    hibernateVersion = '6.2.5.Final'
    microserviceBaseName = 'consents'
    globalVersion = '1.0.0'
    deployDir = 'deploy/application/dist'
    buildType = 'SNAPSHOT'
    microserviceDesc = 'Consents Service'
}

bootJar {
    archiveBaseName = project.property('microserviceBaseName')
    archiveVersion = project.property('globalVersion') + '.' + project.property('buildType')
    destinationDirectory = file(project.property('deployDir'))
}

tasks.register('copyProperties', Copy) {
    from('src/main/resources/')
    into(project.property('deployDir'))
    include('application.properties')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
    doFirst {
        println "Compiler arguments for compileJava task: $options.compilerArgs"
    }
}

processResources.finalizedBy copyProperties

sourceCompatibility = 17
targetCompatibility = 17

dependencyManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}

dependencies {
    configurations.configureEach {
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude group: "org.yaml", module: "snakeyaml"
    }
    implementation 'co.elastic.apm:apm-agent-api:1.36.0'
    implementation 'co.elastic.apm:apm-agent-attach:1.36.0'
    implementation 'co.elastic.logging:log4j2-ecs-layout:1.5.0'
    implementation group: 'com.github.ulisesbocchio', name: 'jasypt-spring-boot-starter', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.9.1'
    implementation('com.lmax:disruptor:4.0.0.RC1')
    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15'
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-http-client")
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-cache")
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-jtf")
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-masterdata")
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-navigation")
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-notifications")
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-platform")
    implementation("in.novopay:infra-service-gateway")
    implementation("in.novopay:util-platform")
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.10.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.0'
    implementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2')
    implementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2')
    implementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.9.2')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20231013'
    implementation group: 'org.owasp.antisamy', name: 'antisamy', version: '1.7.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring6', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'

    testImplementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk18on', version: '1.77'
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.7"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.7"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.7"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:2.0.9"
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:4.11.0')
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.11.0')
    testImplementation group:"org.mockito", name:"mockito-inline", version:"4.2.0"

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.31'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Please add your gradle file to the question.

Comment: Although you have a slew of conflicting JUnit dependencies (none of those you neded as proper versions are already pulled in through `spring-boot-starter-test`. The flyway dependency is old and not sure if that is supported. You have duplicated `kafka-client` dependencies (spring boot already manages the correct and compatible version). I would first cleanup your duplicates. That being said you have some internal dependencies (`in.novopay` I assume) which have to be compiled with `-parameter` as well.

Comment: yes those are configured with `-parameters` flag.

Comment: Well as stated fix your dependencies so it is clear what is in use and figure out what is pulling in things that aren't compiled with `-parameter`.

Comment: build.gradle updated